# How can I save my vim split windows layout?

Tags: vim

I like to split a window(about 10 lines, top of the screen) when I'm writing something, in order to reference some other files easily.

I want to save the windows layout(just the splitting layout without the editing files), so that I can start working quickly.

I tried to put

```
set sessionoptions-=blank
set sessionoptions-=tabpages
set sessionoptions-=winsize
```

in .vimrc and then

```
:mksession file.vim
```

but when I try to `vim -S file.vim`, I can't see the layout but a new windows, why?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
:set sessionoptions=blank,winsize,tabpages,resize
```

When you do -=, you are removing those options from sessionoptions. I assume you probably want to use += instead. By default, sessionoptions is set to buffers,winsize,options,help,blank. By using =, you are getting rid of all the options you don't want.